# how to add custom css using react styled component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a card and I would like to add custom css name using react styled-component. Please suggest me how do I get the below done ?

```
<div className='card custom-css'>
  <span> test </span>
</div>
```

Comment: You can find the info here: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics

Comment: Can you suggest any samples which use { css } from styled-components. I did not find from the given link

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the following ways.

1. Create a new component out of the div that you need to style -
   For eg:

   `<Test>
        <span> test </span>
    </Test>`

Then you can style this component as follows -

```
const Test = styled.div`
  color: blue; /* write your css here */
`
```

2. Style the particular div inside your parent component styling - For eg:

   `const Test = () => (
       <div className='card'>
           <span> test </span>
       </div>
   )`

And style the component as follows -

```
const Test = styled(Test)`
    .card {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    color: blue; /* css for the entire component */
`
```

Also, you can have a particular style for all the div in your component by styling as follows -

```
const Test = styled(Test)`
    div {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    color: blue; /* css for the entire component */
`
```

Refer here for documentation - https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles